# class method not returning value

Tags: c++

I have a method inside a class that is not returning a value.
These are the relevant variables that are being used in the method, they are in the private part of the class

```
int hieght_of_plane = 0 ;
int position_of_plane = 0 ;
bool landing_gear = true ;
bool is_flying = false ;
bool is_alive = true ;
```

And here is the method that is not returning true or false, it is in the public section of the class.

```
    bool check_for_alive()
    {
        if (is_flying == false)
        {
            return true ;
        }
        if (is_flying == true)
        {
            if (hieght_of_plane <= 3)
            {
                if (landing_gear == false)
                {
                    is_alive = false ;
                    return false ;
                }
                else if (landing_gear == true)
                {
                    return true ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The method seems to not do anything and then I get the no return value error

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

I assume that it should return false in this instance because is_flying = false so the method should return false, but it isn't.

Comment: The warning  is produced for the case when `if (hieght_of_plane <= 3)` is false. In this case the method does not return a result.

Comment: What does your method return for the case of `is_flying == true && hieght_of_plane > 3`?

Comment: Also, you don't need separate "if" statements for the `is_flying` and `landing_gear`.  The `else` statements will take care of this, e.g. "if (is_flying) /*...*/ else {/*...*/}`.  The "else if" is not required, make it a simple `else`.

Comment: when ```is_flying == true && height_of_plane > 3``` it still gives me the same warning

Comment: @peterthepiper68: Exactly.  When `is_flying == true && height_of_plane > 3` is true, what value do you expect the method to return and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case that falls through is when `flying == true` and `hieght_of_plane` is greater than 3.

```
    if (is_flying == true)
    {
        if (hieght_of_plane <= 3)
        {
```

The 2nd `if` statement does not have an `else`, which is necessary for returning a value.

**Edit 1: An `else` clause**
The `else` clause should be used for the "not" case of the `if` statement.
For example:

```
if (is_flying == false)
{
    return true;
} 
else // This means is_flying == true
{
    if (hieght_of_plane <= 3)
    {
        if (landing_gear == false)
        {
            is_alive = false ;
            return false ;
        }
        else // implies landing_gear == true
        {
            return true ;
        }
    else // implies hieght > 3
    {
         return ????
    }
}
```

You could also reduce this down to one Boolean expression.

**Edit 2:  Simplification**
There are two functionalities here:  Return `true`/`false` for a combination of conditions and to set `is_alive` based on a condition.
Let's say that one condition is true, all others is false.

```
bool check_for_alive()
{
    if (is_flying && (height_of_plane <= 3) && (landing_gear == false))
    {
        is_alive = false;
    }
    return is_flying && (height_of_plane <= 3) && (landing_gear == true);
}
```

*Note:  The above does not consider the case of `(height_of_plane > 3), since this is not specified in the OP's original code.*

Answer (score 0):

the control flow **would reach** the end of the function when `is_flying is true` and `hieght_of_plane is > 3`. you **MUST** return something there.
and one more thing is the you don't always need to check that `if (something == true)` instead `if (something)` would enough, I've pointed some more below the code.

```c
bool check_for_alive() {
    if (!is_flying)
        return true;

    // if you reached here is_flying is true no need to check
    if (hieght_of_plane <= 3) {
        if (!landing_gear) {
            is_alive = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            // if you're here landing_gear is false no need to check
            return true;
        }
    }

    // what to return if we reach here? yes the control flow could reach
    // here when is_flying is true and hieght_of_plane is > 3
    // you must return something here.
}
```